# How do I load data correctly in Hive using spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I want to input data which looks as-

```
"58;""management"";""married"";""tertiary"";""no"";2143;""yes"";""no"";""unknown"";5;""may"";261;1;-1;0;""unknown"";""no"""
"44;""technician"";""single"";""secondary"";""no"";29;""yes"";""no"";""unknown"";5;""may"";151;1;-1;0;""unknown"";""no"""
"33;""entrepreneur"";""married"";""secondary"";""no"";2;""yes"";""yes"";""unknown"";5;""may"";76;1;-1;0;""unknown"";""no"""
"47;""blue-collar"";""married"";""unknown"";""no"";1506;""yes"";""no"";""unknown"";5;""may"";92;1;-1;0;""unknown"";""no"""
```

My create table statement is as-

```
sqlContext.sql("create table dummy11(age int, job string, marital string, education string, default string, housing string, loan string, contact string, month string, day_of_week string, duration int, campaign int, pday int, previous int, poutcome string, emp_var_rate int, cons_price_idx int, cons_conf_idx int, euribor3m int, nr_employed int, y string)row format delimited fields terminated by ';'")
```

When I run the statement-

```
sqlContext.sql("from dummy11 select age").show()
```

OR

```
sqlContext.sql("from dummy11 select y").show()
```

It returns `NULL` value instead of correct values, though other values are visible

So how do I correct this??

Comment: how did you read the data ?

Comment: When you consider about your first record; It has 17 fields (considering `;` as delim), but in your query, you defined 21 fields, is that correct!!

Comment: sqlContext.sql("load data inpath 'hdfs://user/nikita.jaiswal25_gmail/dataset.csv' into table dummy11")

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi  Yes that is correct...how do I get that read correctly??  I have to declare those fields as well because my data set is large. Its just the dummy 4 rows which I have taken  for checking the error. Rest of the data may have 21 values as well.. Is this type of input possible in Hive.

Comment: Delimeter is required even if those records does not have any values - in hive.

----->>> So, as per the query, first 17 fields (from the DDL you defined) are populated with the values; and rest are populated as NULL.

Comment: @NikitaJaiswal, So, Last column `y` is comming as NULL; and first column's data type is `INT`; but the data has `"` character in first field position. so, age is comming as NULL.

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi Thanks for the answer..could you help me modifying the querry..I cannot put 'age' as string as I have to do further calculations using this 'age' column.

Comment: @NikitaJaiswal your sample data has 17 fields whereas your sql query has 21 fields, how are managing to populate all the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Hive QL syntax, you need to validate the input data before processing.

In your data, few records have lesser columns - than the actual columns defined in DDL.

So, for those records, the rest columns (from last) are set as NULL; as that row does not have enough values.

That's why, the last column `y` has values `NULL`.

Also, in DDL, first field's data type is `INT`; but in record, first field values are:

```
"58
"44
"33
```

Because of `"`, the values are not type-casted to `INT`; setting field value as `NULL`.

As per the DDL and data - you provided, values are getting set as:

```
age             "58
job             ""management""
marital         ""married""
education       ""tertiary""
default         ""no""
housing         2143
loan            ""yes""
contact         ""no""
month           ""unknown""
day_of_week     5
duration        ""may""
campaign        261
pday            1
previous        -1
poutcome        0
emp_var_rate    ""unknown""
cons_price_idx  ""no""
cons_price_idx  NULL
cons_conf_idx   NULL
euribor3m int   NULL
nr_employed     NULL
y               NULL
```

Check the `NULL` values for last 5 columns.

So, if that is not expected, you need to validate the data first before proceeding.

And for the column `age`, if you need it in `INT` type, cleanse the data to remove unwanted `"` character.

---

> **WORKAROUND**

As workaround, you can define `age` as `STRING` at beginning, as use spark transformations to parse the first field and convert it to `INT`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val ageInINT = udf { (make: String) =>
  Integer.parseInt(make.substring(1))
}
df.withColumn("ageInINT", ageInINT(df("age"))).show
```

Here `df` is your dataframe created while executing the hive DDL with column `age` as `sTRING`.

Nnow, you can perform operation on new column `ageInINT` rather than column `age` with `INTEGER` values.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data contains `"` just before the age, it is considered as string. In the code you have defined it as `int` therefore sql parser is trying to find the integer value and therefore you are getting the `null` record. Change the `age int` with `age string` and you will be able to see the result.

Please see below working example Using Spark `HiveContext`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql("create external table dummy11(age string, job string, marital string, education string, default string, housing string, loan string, contact string, month string, day_of_week string, duration int, campaign int, pday int, previous int, poutcome string, emp_var_rate int, cons_price_idx int, cons_conf_idx int, euribor3m int, nr_employed int, y string)row format delimited fields terminated by ';' location '/user/skumar143/stack/'")
sqlContext.sql("select age, job from dummy11").show()
```

Its output:

```
+---+----------------+
|age|             job|
+---+----------------+
|"58|  ""management""|
|"44|  ""technician""|
|"33|""entrepreneur""|
|"47| ""blue-collar""|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: Here you have declared `age` as string..I need to use `age` in calculations further. I cannot keep it as `string` as it will not be calculated. We need to make it to `int` so that it can be used for mathematical calculations.

Comment: Then please use different approach to parse the data. create a dataframe and temporary table to parse the data and then load it into final table. Other workaround is to convert this column into numeric type or remove all wanted `"`.